# Is the following acceptable: was expecting + if I hadn't had

Tags: conditionals, past-perfect

I sent an email recently to a hotel where I'm going to stay, but I got a flight cancelation. Here's a passage from my email,

> I had my flight canceled today, I **was expecting** to arrive at the hotel in time for the checking, if I **hadn't had** this cancelation…"

My question is whether I can say

> I was expecting… if I hadn't had…

Is this construction grammatically correct or acceptable? Or maybe I should've used something like, *…would have expected*...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: *My flight got cancelled today*. *If it hadn't happened so, I would have checked in*.

Comment: *"In time **to check in**."* *For the checking* is unidiomatic in this context.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tense issue and there's a word choice problem.

Your second thought was correct. The phrase *if I hadn't VERBed* is a past conditional, so requires *I would have VERBed*.  For example, *If I hadn't missed my flight, I would have arrived this evening.*

But this makes the verb following *I would have* hypothetical and the *expecting* you were doing actually happened. It was not hypothetical, it was real. Thus this structure does not work.

If you want to keep *if it hadn't happened*, you need a different hypothetical action, e.g. *I would have arrived at the hotel in time for **check-in** [not "checking"] if the flight hadn't been canceled.*

Or, if you want to keep *expected*, the mood of the second part of the sentence needs to change, e.g. *I was expecting to arrive at the hotel in time for check-in, but the flight was canceled.*